# How to reset filters of a react-table when doing server-side filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm using version 6.7.6 of react-table library.I am doing server-side filtering with my react-table. I have several tabs, and I am looking for a way to reset the filters of my table when I change the current tab.

If I add

`filtered={this.state.filtered}
 onFilteredChange={filtered => this.setState({ filtered })}`

it works, but in that case the backend is called twice each time a character is typed in a filter area, because I have the manual prop.
I don't know if it's a normal behavior and if it's possible to avoid this double call.

Use https://codesandbox.io/embed/w7jj9mqv88 to reproduce the issue.

Steps to reproduce the issue :

1. Type a character in a filter area
2. Click on the other tab
3. Notice the value typed in the filter area is still there

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm facing the same issue and don't know how to deal with it.